# I get an error with a ternary operator, but not in the console, why?

Tags: reactjs

why do I get the error although when I do a console output I get the correct value?

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id_pdf' of undefined

```
   {ergebnis.map((e, index) => (
  //The error is not thrown. All works
   {console.log(gemerkt[index].id_pdf)}

 
   <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
   //The error is thrown here and the array is not null or empty
              {gemerkt.length &&  gemerkt[index].id_pdf === e.id ? (
                <StarIcon
                  onClick={() => toggleStart(index, e.id)}
                  style={{ color: "#E69123", cursor: "pointer" }}
                ></StarIcon>
              ) : (
                <StarBorderIcon
                  onClick={() => toggleStart(index, e.id)}
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                />
              )}
   </IconButton>
```

[image]

Comment: The statement which is generating the error is incomplete After the first check of the && In the second condition check only ? is visible. The colon(:) false statement is missing

Comment: Can't help with one line of code.

Comment: May be this would fail for a particular iteration or a particular index for which the array gemerkt does not have an element

Comment: Check gemerkt[index].id_pdf == undefined and get the values of index for which iteration it fails

Comment: Have EDIT my Post

Comment: This will happen for example when the `index` is equal to `3`.

Answer (score 0):

check if `gemerkt[index].id_pdf` is undefined then do the check with `e.id` if it not

```
 <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
 //The error is thrown here and the array is not null or empty
              {gemerkt.length &&  
               (gemerkt[index].id_pdf ? gemerkt[index].id_pdf : -1) === e.id ? (
                <StarIcon
                  onClick={() => toggleStart(index, e.id)}
                  style={{ color: "#E69123", cursor: "pointer" }}
                ></StarIcon>
              ) : (
                <StarBorderIcon
                  onClick={() => toggleStart(index, e.id)}
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                />
              )}
   </IconButton>
```